# MySQL indexes on query with Where, GroupBy and OrderBy clauses

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, indices

How can i improve the performance of below query? What indexes might help?

```
SELECT platform, country, Source, window,
Round(SUM(ProjectedARPI*PlayerCount) / SUM(PlayerCount), 2) AS ProjectedARPI, 
Round(SUM(ProjectedARPIOrganicLow*PlayerCount) / SUM(PlayerCount), 2) AS ProjectedARPIOrganicLow, 
Round(SUM(ProjectedARPIOrganicMed*PlayerCount) / SUM(PlayerCount), 2) AS ProjectedARPIOrganicMed, 
Round(SUM(ProjectedARPIOrganicHigh*PlayerCount) / SUM(PlayerCount), 2) AS ProjectedARPIOrganicHigh, 
SUM(PlayerCount) AS PlayerCount, SUM(PayerCount) AS PayerCount, 
CASE WHEN(SUM(PlayerCount) > 500 AND SUM(PayerCount) > 10) THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END AS isSignificant, 
ProjectionDate, 
min(CohortRangeLow) as CohortRangeLow, 
max(CohortRangeHigh) as CohortRangeHigh 
FROM web_synch.UI_data 
WHERE PlayerCount > 0 AND ProjectionDate BETWEEN '2015-07-25' AND '2016-10-25' AND window = 365 
GROUP BY Platform, country, source, ProjectionDate 
ORDER BY Platform, source, ProjectionDate;
```

Comment: You can start with some attempt at formatting the query.  I understand you are new to the site, but the query is a mess.  If it can't be read, it can't be improved.

Comment: Thanks Bobski for editing the post.

Comment: my please always add 4 spaces before code

Comment: Sure, will do that.

Answer (score 0):

For this query, basically your only hope in using indexes is either:  `UI_data(window, ProjectionDate, PlayerCount)` or `UI_data(window, PlayerCount, ProjectionDate)`.  Which is better depends on which selects fewer records . . . I would guess the first is better.

Comment: Thanks Gordon for the response! Just want to understand why an index for GROUP-BY columns work here ?

Comment: (Pls ignore above comment) Thanks Gordon for the response! Just want to understand why an index for GROUP-BY columns would not work here ?

Comment: Along with your suggested index for WHERE clause, i also added an index for the GROUP-BY clause. But when the query ran, it only used the index for where clause and not the index for group clause.

Comment: @Mayank . . . In general, queries only use one index per table (this is a generalization, but I think it is always true for MySQL).

Comment: Sure Gordon, Thanks !

Comment: @Mayank . . . An index for `GROUP BY` columns doesn't work in MySQL, because MySQL almost never uses an index for `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Gordon - As an experiment i removed the index for the where clause and instead added an index for groupby clause. So next time i ran the query, it took the index for "GroupBy" clause. I am using MySQL 5.7 on Amazon RDS. Any thoughts why would that happen ?

Comment: There is some performance to be gained -- the sort for doing the `GROUP BY` would be avoided.  You cannot (in your query as it stands) use indexing both for the filtering (`WHERE`) and `GROUP BY`.  And you are stuck with a sort for the `ORDER BY` (since it differs from the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @Mayank . . . That surprises me.   Your query doesn't meet the requirements (as I read them) for either a loose index scan or full index scan as described in the documentation (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-optimization.html).

Comment: Thanks Rick for the feedback !

Comment: Gordon - I tried again and surprisingly it did pickup index for groupby clause in absence of index for where clause.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that this is the best index:

```
INDEX(window,          -- first because "="
      ProjectionDate   -- range
     )                 -- nothing after range will be looked at
```

This has a slight advantage over the 3-column index previously suggested, in that the index will be slightly smaller.

More discussion: [*Index cookbook*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/building-the-best-index-for-a-given-select/) .

I expect there will be two sorts -- one for `GROUP BY`, then one for `ORDER BY`.  It would run a little faster if you made the `ORDER BY` and the `GROUP BY` list identical.

Possible bug:  if `ProjectionDate` is a `DATE` datatype, then the range is three months plus one day.  Recommend this pattern:

```
    ProjectionDate >= '2015-07-25'
AND ProjectionDate  < '2016-07-25' + INTERVAL 3 MONTH
```

Comment: Thanks Rick for the feedback. I will try both your suggestions and see the improvements. Also will check for the possible bug you mentioned.